# Signal division into parts on chart

Tags: matlab, math, charts, fft, physics

I have a signal from an interferometer, which is then filtered by FFT (fast Fourier transform) the filter itself works ok.
For now i filter the signal in range which i choose, i can also do this in whole range, but i want cut this signal into parts and filter/analysis each parts, it can be done automaticly, or i can enter the range which i want. To cut this i must probably use some window ?

The screenshot of the program:

[image]

[image]

the link to the all files: [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GTQOJe53JGoIkdOxEIQY6TEpMoaSksxG), [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bTfrb2nRcvPfZrAKY9CSJEz13-TmDlOY) and [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15aOf1XSS9QIlUmUgkhHUWFQprAZWO6Yh).

**My Code:**

```
clear all; 
close all; 
clc; 
file_name = 'W0009.dat';
[lam, I] = read_spectrum(file_name);
lam = lam*1e-3;
figure(1)
plot(lam,I, '-k');hold on;

mask = lam >= 1.6 & lam <= 1.8;
N = sum(mask);
w = hamming(N);

if mod(N, 2) == 0
    f = (-fix(N/2) : fix(N/2) - 1)/N; % czestotliwości dla N parzystego
else
    f = (-fix(N/2) : fix(N/2))/N; % czestotliwości  dla N nieparzystego
end

F = 2*fftshift(fft(I(mask)))/N;
W = fftshift(fft(I(mask).*w));

m = abs(f) <= 0.04;
F(not(m)) = 0;

figure(2)
semilogy(f, abs(F), '-k');hold on;
% semilogy(f, abs(W), '-r');hold on;

fI = -abs(N*ifft(fftshift(F))/2);
figure(3);
plot(lam(mask), I(mask), '-k');hold on;
plot(lam(mask), fI, '-r');

% M = 258; b = fir1(M, 0.45);
% I1 = I;
% I1 = filter(b, 1, I1); I1(1 : end - floor(M/2)) = I1(floor(M/2) + 1 : end);
% I1 = filtfilt(b, 1, I1);
% plot(lam,I1);hold on;
% 
% M = 38; b = fir1(M, 0.15);
% I2 = I;
% I2 = filter(b, 1, I2); I2(1 : end - floor(M/2)) = I2(floor(M/2) + 1 : end);
% I2 = filtfilt(b, 1, I2);
% plot(lam,I2);hold on;
% 
% M = 52; b = fir1(M, 0.05);
% I3 = I;
% I3 = filter(b, 1, I3); I3(1 : end - floor(M/2)) = I3(floor(M/2) + 1 : end);
% I3 = filtfilt(b, 1, I3);
% plot(lam,I3);hold on;
% 
% fm1 = lam < 1.8394 & lam > 1.5584;
% Ifinal1 = I1(fm1);
% fm2 = lam > 1.8394 & lam < 1.98138;
% Ifinal2 = I2(fm2);
% fm3 = lam < 2.216 & lam > 1.98138;
% Ifinal3 = I3(fm3);
% lamfinal = [lam(fm1);lam(fm2);lam(fm3)];
% Ifinal = [Ifinal1;Ifinal2;Ifinal3];
% close;
% figure(2)
% plot(lamfinal,Ifinal); hold on;
% 
% nlam = linspace(lamfinal(1), lamfinal(end), 9*length(lamfinal)).';
% nI = interp1(lamfinal, Ifinal, nlam, 'spline');
% plot(nlam,nI);
% 
% close;
% figure(3)
% [PKS1,LOCS1]= findpeaks(nI);
% plot(nlam,nI);hold on;
% plot(nlam(LOCS1),PKS1,'or'); hold on;
% [PKS2,LOCS2]= findpeaks(-nI,'MinPeakWidth',25);
% % PKS1 = [PKS1(1:73);PKS1(75:end)];
% % LOCS1 = [LOCS1(1:73);LOCS1(75:end)];
% % PKS2 = [PKS2(1:75);PKS2(77:end)];
% % LOCS2 = [LOCS2(1:75);LOCS2(77:end)];
% plot(nlam(LOCS2),-PKS2,'or');
% axis tight;
```

Comment: I have still no idea what criteria you want to use to "cut the signal in parts". How would you do it manually? What parts would you select?

Comment: If the analysis ranges are known a priori you can in deed just program a loop working on all three ranges. If you need to define your range boundaries by some algorithm it would be more difficult. I will put a suggestion on the loop in an answer.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To analyse three parameter ranges you can define these first and the process them in a loop

```
% Definition of ranges
ranges = [1.2,1.6 ; 1.6, 1.8 ; 1.8, 2.4];
% Number of ranges defined
nRanges = size(ranges,1);
% loop over ranges
for i=1:nRanges
  % ... some stuff from your program
  % Define the masking area
  mask = lam >= ranges(i,1) & lam <= ranges(i,2);
  % ... more stuff from your program
end
```

You should be able to modify your program in this way.

Comment: If you can not explain in your words how the range should be subdivided, how should you then be able to write an algorithm doing that job for you? Please go back to your desk, do your homework and think about what you want your algorithm to do for you. I could not figure it out from your words yet. Sorry